# installing a package from debian/rules

Tags: debian

My debian package source builds three packages, dev, dbg and the library. The dev package is a build dependency for another package that builds later on.

Is there a way to install this newly generated dev package on the build machine from debian/rules file?

I was thinking of putting "dpkg -i dev-pkg-name.deb" in the install: portion of the rules file.

NOTE: PROBLEM IS SOLVED, and I don't know how to remove this question.

Comment: Are all the packages in .deb files?

Comment: @Asmageddon, Yes, it generates 3 .deb files. One of these is needed to be installed on the build machine.

Comment: Figured that this can be done via an install script, but not from debian/rules.

Comment: @GauravSinha: The right way to "remove" the question is to self-answer and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of dependencies is the job of the build system (e.g. `pbuilder` or `buildd`), not of your debian rules. The only place for assumptions about the orders of compilation or even the existence of other packages is the `Build-Depends` field in control. `Build-Depends` is picked up by the build control software and determines which packages are installed during the build of a particular software.